# Set column to a concatenated value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, concatenation

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2008:

`Address`:

```
nameid | e-mail
---------------
1      | xyz@abc.com
2      | fgh@asdf.com
3      | 123@doremi.com
```

`Member`:

```
nameid | memberid
---------------
1      | 456
2      | 457
3      | 458
```

I need to set e-mail to `[memberid]@test.com` keeping in mind that e-mail is `varchar` and `memberid` is `int`.

Comment: Are you saying each member will have `@test.com`?

Comment: yeah, their memberid@test.com

Comment: is there any significance for the `address` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.nameid 
      ,CAST(M.memberid AS NVARCHAR(20)) + 
           RIGHT([e_mail], LEN([e_mail]) - CHARINDEX('@', [e_mail])+1) AS New_Column
FROM [address] A INNER JOIN [member] M
ON A.nameid = M.nameid
```

To simply hardcode `@test.com` with their MemberID is fairly simple

```
SELECT A.nameid 
      ,CAST(M.memberid AS VARCHAR(20)) + '@test.com' AS New_Column

FROM [address] A INNER JOIN [member] M
ON A.nameid = M.nameid
```

Comment: Seeing that `memberid` is a `int` - why would you be converting this to a `nvarchar`? Numbers really don't need a Unicode representation.... I don't see any reason for that or benefit from it - especially since the OP said the `email` was a `varchar`. Seems like you're causing unnecessary implicit casts when joining the two ....

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update a
    set email = cast(m.memberid as varchar(255)) + '@test.com'
    from address a join
         member m
         on a.nameid = m.nameid;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT CAST(memberid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@test.com'
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is a new function in SQL Server **2012** and thus not available to someone running SQL Server **2008** ....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use this based on the comments...

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), memberid) + '@Test.com' FROM member
```